# PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/padtvro/public_html/wp-content/themes/claudia/content.php on line 30

Tags: php

In the cpanel error log WordPress generates this error:

> PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach () in
>   /home/padtvro/public_html/wp-content/themes/claudia/content.php on
>   line 30

If I delete it, it appears again in 6-7 hours. What's the problem?

```
<section id="contents" class="clearfix"><div class="row main_content"><div class="container content_wraper"><?php the_breadcrumb(); ?><div class="grid_8" id="content"><div class="widget_container content_page"><?php require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/include/cat.php'; ?> 
</div></div><div class="grid_4 p7ehc-a" id="sidebar">
<?php $ge_sidebar = '';
                 if (is_search()) {
                      $ge_sidebar = of_get_option('se_sidebar','');
                    }else if(is_category() ) {

                        $category = get_the_category();                     

                        $cn_sidebar ='';
                        foreach($category as $ca_id) {
                            if(empty($cn_sidebar)) { $cn_sidebar = of_get_option('cat_'.$ca_id->term_id);}                              

                        }

                        if(empty($cn_sidebar)) {
                            $ge_sidebar = of_get_option('cat_sidebar','');
                        } else { $ge_sidebar = $cn_sidebar; }


                    } else if(is_author() ) {

                        $ge_sidebar = of_get_option('au_sidebar','');

                    }else if(is_tag() ) {

                        $tags = get_the_tags();                     

                        $cn_sidebar ='';
                        foreach($tags as $tg_id) {
                            if(empty($cn_sidebar)) { $cn_sidebar = of_get_option('tag_'.$tg_id->term_id);}                              
                        }

                        if(empty($cn_sidebar)) {
                            $ge_sidebar = of_get_option('tag_sidebar','');
                        } else { $ge_sidebar = $cn_sidebar; }
                    }               



                $dyn_sidebar ='';
                if(!empty($ge_sidebar)) {   $dyn_sidebar = $ge_sidebar; };              

                foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar ) {
                    if($sidebar['name'] == $dyn_sidebar)
                        {
                             $dyn_sidebar = $sidebar['id'];
                        }
                } 

                if(!empty($dyn_sidebar)) {
                    if (is_active_sidebar($dyn_sidebar)) : dynamic_sidebar($dyn_sidebar);
                    endif;  
                } else{
                    if (is_active_sidebar('center-sidebar')) : dynamic_sidebar('center-sidebar');
                    endif;
                }

    ?></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div></section>
```

Comment: Is this from a theme you developed, or one you bought/downloaded. If it's from another developer you need to raise the issue with them so that they can resolve the issue in a way that will be safe from updates.

Answer (score 1):

The error is generated by this code:

```
line 27 $tags = get_the_tags();                     
line 28
line 29                    $cn_sidebar ='';
line 30                    foreach($tags as $tg_id) {
```

If a post has no tags, [`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/) wil return false. Then supplying `false` to the `foreach` statement will get you the error mentioned. In order to prevent this you should wrap the `foreach` in `if (!empty($tags)) { foreach ...}`.

Comment: Wedding where and how to change,
Can't edit that code?

Comment: And the solution which is please?
Because the person who made my site died of Covid!

Comment: The solution is in the last line of the answer.

Comment: Edit the code directly, put it where you need it, so we don't make any extra mistakes. THX